# Read Arabic lettering in html into csv using Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, csv, arabic

I am Working with Html that has Arabic lettering in it. I am trying to parse the lettering into a csv file that opens as default in Excel.

I am using a Perl script to parse the lettering out however I thought by using

`use feature 'unicode_strings';`

in the Perl this would allow the csv to store Arabic lettering however it does not.

Is there a way round this?

Comment: Sorry, this is not a [good problem description](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) as no one is able to [reproduce what goes wrong](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html#showmehow) and we are left to guesswork. Show your code. Provide sample input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use autodie qw(:all);
use Web::Query qw(wq);
use Text::CSV_XS qw();

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1})
    or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV_XS->error_diag;
open my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'm.csv';
$csv->print($fh, [wq(
    '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head><title></title></head><body>&#x645;&#x643;&#x629; &#x623;&#x648;
    &#x645;&#x643;&#x629; &#x627;&#x644;&#x645;&#x643;&#x631;&#x645;&#x629;
    &#x647;&#x64a; &#x645;&#x62f;&#x64a;&#x646;&#x629;
    &#x645;&#x642;&#x62f;&#x633;&#x629; &#x644;&#x62f;&#x649;
    &#x627;&#x644;&#x645;&#x633;&#x644;&#x645;&#x64a;&#x646;&#x60c;
    &#x628;&#x647;&#x627; &#x627;&#x644;&#x645;&#x633;&#x62c;&#x62f;
    &#x627;&#x644;&#x62d;&#x631;&#x627;&#x645;&#x60c;
    &#x648;&#x627;&#x644;&#x643;&#x639;&#x628;&#x629; &#x627;&#x644;&#x62a;&#x64a;
    &#x62a;&#x639;&#x62f; &#x642;&#x628;&#x644;&#x629;
    &#x627;&#x644;&#x645;&#x633;&#x644;&#x645;&#x64a;&#x646; &#x641;&#x64a;
    &#x635;&#x644;&#x627;&#x62a;&#x647;&#x645;.</body></html>'
)->find('body')->text]);
close $fh;
```

Comment: You couldn't give a quick explanation of what your script does could you please?

Comment: Quick explanation: HTML with Arabic writing is parsed and written into a CSV file. – Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7661910/edit) and fill in the [lacking information](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7661910#comment-9358313).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Encode::Arabic](http://search.cpan.org/~smrz/Encode-Arabic-1.16/Arabic.pm); see if that helps the parsing.